# Regex to suppress line breaks to aggregate groups of 3 lines into 1

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm trying to fix a txt file format using python and regex. For that I used this [post](https://medium.com/@zaishanweng/data-cleaning-on-sap-data-extracts-with-regex-and-python-cd2afe73be14) as a point of start, but I can't make it work with my file format.

Regex:

```
([^1|-])[\n](.)|(.)[\n]([^|-])
```

My file format is something like this:

```
|A  |B  |C  |
 D  |E  |
F  |G  |
```

I want to parse it like this:

```
|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |G  |
```

Without removing any separator pipes or content just the newline breaks between then.

The problem is that it replaces the pipes and other chars that are near the line breaks.

[image: Problem Example]

What do I need to change in the regex?

Comment: Maybe `txt = txt.replace('\n', '')` is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `([^1|-])\n(.)|(.)\n([^|-])` uses an alternation with 2 capture groups on the left and the right, matching 3 characters in total on each side.

So if you want the capture group data in the result, you would have to use those groups in the replacement.

But this negated character class `[^1|-]` can also match a space or newline, and does not take multiple whitespace chars into account.

---

What you might do is match a pipe followed by optional spaces around a newline, and in the replacement use a single pipe.

```
\|[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4yAjNa/1).

```
import re

regex = r"\|[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*"

s = ("|A  |B  |C  |\n"
            " D  |E  |\n"
            "F  |G  |")

print(re.sub(regex, '|', s))
```

Output

```
|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |G  |
```

---

As `\s` *can* also match a newline, a shorter option could be using `regex = r"\|\s+"` but then it will also match spaces after the pipe when there is no newline present.